# Delete confirmation issue on iPhone

Tags: iphone

[image]

I have added a light white/gray color to the background to see what happens when the "Delete Confirmation" is on. My problem is that when the delete button animates on screen, it does not reposition the content of my cell so I have this strange overlapping issue. Could anybody please help me? Do I have to make my own animation etc for this? Thank you.

---

EDIT ADDED CODE: (I have removed the autoresizing because I don't get it to work..)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *LogCellId = @"LogCellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LogCellId];

    UILabel *lblSummary;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:LogCellId] autorelease];   
        lblSummary = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 260.0, 30.0)] autorelease];
        lblSummary.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        lblSummary.tag = SUMMARY_TAG;
        lblSummary.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
        lblSummary.opaque = YES;
        lblSummary.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0/255.0 green:240.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblSummary];

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0/255.0 green:240.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    } else {
        lblSummary = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:SUMMARY_TAG];
    }

    lblSummary.text = [self.logList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most likely added your control/s to the cell-view itself. Dont do that but add your control/s to the `UITableViewCell.contentView` - that will make sure that your cell gets properly animated when switching to edit-mode.

*Added after seeing the updated question*

Also make sure your just control/s have `autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;` set.

Comment: Thank you! I set the UIViewAutoreszingFlexibleWidth on the label and now it works, I thought I had tried that as well but obviously I had not done that.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you did you cell. But the autoresizeMask property might help ;)

Answer (score 0):

"The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. **If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.**"

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView